# Semantic release not accepting GITLAB_TOKEN on gitlab private repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, semantic-release

Here is the error log message:

> [3:40:55 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  The command "git push --dry-run
> --no-verify https://gitlab-ci-token:[secure]@[repository-url].git
> HEAD:main" failed with the error message remote: You are not allowed
> to upload code.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[secure]@[repository-url]/': The requested URL returned error: 403.

I have a `GITLAB_TOKEN` set up in the repository settings with all the necessary permissions, but it seems it isn't even being used:

[image]

Here is my `.releaserc.json` config:

```
{
  "branches": ["main", { "name": "beta", "prerelease": true }],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    "@semantic-release/gitlab",
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "CHANGELOG.md"],
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here it's my `.gitlab-ci.yml` config:

```
# NodeJs image
image: node:16

# STAGES
stages:
  - checks
  - build
  - release

# SETUP
before_script:
  - node -v
  - npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken ${NPM_TOKEN}
  - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline

# JOBS
lint:
  stage: checks
  script:
    - npm run lint

test:
  stage: checks
  script:
    - npm run test:ci

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build

release:
  stage: release
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - npx semantic-release
```

And here are the semantic release dependencies I'm using and it's versions:

```
"@semantic-release/changelog": "^6.0.1",
"@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
"@semantic-release/gitlab": "^7.0.4",
"@semantic-release": "^19.0.2",
```

The `GITLAB_TOKEN` is a member of the repository as a maintainer (just like the other repositories where semantic release is working):

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that this problem (and its fix) are specific to GitLab - the method is somewhat different on GitHub for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in the end the problem was that I had to add the created `GITLAB_TOKEN` access token in `Settings > CI/CD > Variables`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved after adding **two** variables to the Gitlab environment variables which is located at `Settings > CI/CD > Variables`:

- GITLAB_URL
- GITLAB_TOKEN

For more information, checkout [the repository](https://github.com/semantic-release/gitlab/).